# usage of b-tree index for multiple columns in the table

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, indexing

As far as I know one of the most common indexes in the database is the one that uses `b-tree`.

If I have the index for integer column

```
column1 column2
   2     name2
   3     name3
   1     name4
```

it might create the index that looks like this

```
 2
| |
1 3
```

If I use `column2` it might create it like this

```
   name2
 |      |
name1 name3
```

But if I have a composite index with two fields, how it's gonna order it then? Will it just go with basic comparisons for two columns?

Is there some other additional optimizations that database does for index structure?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (This is a product specific question, since products implement indexes differently.)

Comment: @jarlh ho, so depends on vendor the b-tree index may vary? I thought the all use the same algorithms

Comment: @jarlh I am interested in general overview regarding all dbms. Though I use postgres myself

Comment: Well, perhaps they do. Still better to get answers from people who know Postgresql.

Comment: @jarlh I do not particularly care about vendor. I just want to look at how it is implemented in general regardless dbms

Comment: Probably the most detailed description is here: https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/backend/access/nbtree/README

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The multiple keys are all used together in the index:

```
     2,name2
     |     |
1,name4  3,name3
```

The comparison is made on the first key.  Only in the case of ties, does the next key get used.  So, if all the numbers were the same you would have:

```
     2,name2
     |     |
2,name3  2,name4
```

Comment: So If I put `2, name5` for the first case, it will send it to the right to `3, name3` leaf?

Comment: If you have `2, name5` then the "2"s are equal, and `name5` > `name2` so it would go to the right.

Comment: I see. But in the end it is basically a separate structure that is referenced from the original table?

Comment: @lapots . . . Yes.  Postgres doesn't even support clustered indexes, so the structure is always separate.  In databases that support a clustered index, the leaf nodes of the cluster index are the data pages.  But the actual hierarchy of the index is always separate from the data.

Comment: so hierarchy is a separate entity? I thought it stored everything as a single structure

Comment: @lapots . . . Indexes are separate entities.  Whether they are "part of a table" is more of a logical question.  The data for the index is not stored on the data pages used for the table.

Comment: I got that indexes are separate entities, but I am not sure I understand how it stores hierarchy (as far as I understand index data is stored as some kind of ordered set)

Comment: @lapots . . . The keys are duplicated in the index structure.  I think there might be documentation on the detailed structure.